# Prove that the $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}h(x,y)$ Does not Exist using Polar Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $h(x,y)=\frac{x^5y}{2x^{10}+y^2}$. How would I prove that the $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}h(x,y)$ Does Not Exist?

I think that we might use polar coordinates, but I am not sure.

Comment: Hint: Try the pseudo-polar change of variables $$x=r\cos(\theta)\qquad y=r^5\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: @Did Is it possible to show that the limit DNE by using polar coordinates?

Comment: @Did I don't understand what you mean there

Comment: As written in my first comment, the way to solve this by a change of coordinates is to use the not-quite-polar change of coordinates I indicated. Did you even *try* to use this idea? What exactly don't you understand in it?

Comment: @Did I didnt know that you could take y=r^5...

Comment: Where did I suggest to "take y=r^5" (whatever that means)? Please read.

Comment: @did You said $y=r^5sin(\theta)$

Comment: Yes I said that. Which is not the same as y=r^5. Say, where is this conversation going, exactly?

Comment: @Did I just want to know how I can prove that the above limit DNE. How can I do that. I haven't yet gotten an answer to my understanding and I really want to know because I got 0 just like 'Fatih' did. I don't quite understand what cooper.hat is trying to say. I want a way that I can understand and which leads me to the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, and since @copper.hat's indications are crystal clear to anybody even vaguely acquainted to the subject of limits, it seems that the onus is on you to explain what it is you do not understand in this solution. Rather immodestly I happen to think that the same applies to my hint. By the way, **did you try to apply my hint**? If you did, **where were you stopped**? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did I did apply your hint and reached the point: $$\frac{\cos^5(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{2\cos^{10}(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)}$$

Comment: OK, and now, if the limit existed, this should not depend on $\theta$, right? Hence... (Exercise: Embed this approach in @copper.hat's answer.)

Comment: @Did Okay so how do I work with $\theta$ now?

Comment: You definitely **do not read** what people write, do you?

Comment: @Did I did, I just have no idea what is going on in cooper.hat's approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the two paths $t \mapsto (t,t)$ and $t \mapsto (t,t^5)$. The limits will be different.

Explicitly:

Consider the sequence $x_n = {1 \over n}, y_n = {1 \over n}$. Then show that
$h(x_n,y_n) \to 0$.

Now consider the sequence $x_n = {1 \over n}, y_n = {1 \over n^5}$. Then show that
$h(x_n,y_n) \to {1 \over 3}$ (in fact, $h(x_n,y_n) = {1 \over 3}$).

Comment: I dont unerstand/learned this

Comment: I wanted to do this using polar coordinates

Comment: Go ahead. You might want to update your question so people don't waste their time trying to help with alternative approaches.

Comment: Can you do it that way?

Comment: You can. ${}{}{}$

Comment: But I keep getting 0. So I wanted to see someone else do it

Comment: Great! Go ahead.

Comment: What do you mean by "go ahead"

Comment: Why is this downvoted? (+1 from me.) This solution is correct, it goes to the root of the problem and it does answer the question as it was written at the time. (Rather amusingly, by contrast, the (presently) upvoted answer is (presently) squarely wrong.)

Comment: @Did: Much appreciated. I'm having a bad MSE day :-). This comment will self destruct in 10 seconds.

Comment: Please, please, do not let petty MSE events reach you... We know they are often absurd, don't we?

Comment: @Did: I need a life :-).

Comment: @Did: Perserverance pays off. (Funny story related to that, but better shared over a glass of wine :-).)